# window.XXX = require(YYY) VS const {XXX} = require(YYY): which to use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel

The title says everything I want to ask. I cannot understand what are the key differences in using window and const {}.

I tried both and the result is the same. Can you help me understanding this?

P.S. I am using Laravel and it is using window global variable. Some libraries show method with const {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `window.XXX = require(YYY)` assigns the object returned from `require(YYY)` call to `XXX` variable on the `window` object. But `const {XXX} = require(YYY)` uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to unpack the property `XXX` from the object returned by `require(YYY)`. So calling `const {XXX} = require(YYY)` in `window` scope will be equal to `window.XXX = require(YYY).XXX`. Now to the question *which to use?* the answer is which ever you need in the specific case.

Comment: And what do you prefer to use? Can I mix both variants or I have to stick to something?

Comment: @Nod Prefer? It depends on your case of use. If you want global variable to be available everywhere, you use window.xxx if you don't wan't to accidentaly reassign variable from other place you use const.

Comment: You can use both. It depends if you need the whole object returned from `require(YYY)` or just one or few of it's member properties. You can do `const {XXX, ZZZ} = require(YYY)` if you need `XXX` and `ZZZ`

Comment: That’s it. Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

`require` may be old method - it depends on your enviroment.

```
const foo = require('bar');
//is almost the same as
imrport foo from 'bar';
```

Import method have more posibilities eg:

```
//file foo.js
export const myStr = 'lol';
export default (x)=>x**4;
export * as lol from './someFile';
```

Other file:

```
import {myStr, lol}, defaultExported from './foo';
```

The idea is to encapsulate variables to not accidentaly reassign in two places same variable, so window may be not needed anymore. If you need some variable/const you import it in other file.
If you need backward compatibility in your enviroment, you use babel (here is online version) https://babeljs.io/repl/
You know laravel, so beware of some differences in JavaScript const:

```
const foo = 1;
foo = 2; //error
const arr = [1];
arr[0]++; //[2]
arr[1] = 'lol'; //no error
const obj = {};
obj.lol = 'man'; //it works
```